# Install XPH on wiped W7H Netbook?

Tags: windows

Too old and tired to keep up with the 'reinvented the wheel' every year or so.

I've mistakenly picked up a very clean, but wiped 2009 Acer One (AOD250) Netbook (presuming it'd been running XPH), but the puppy was designed to run W7H, which might I'm guessing might make running XPH on it impossible.

Needless to say the thing won't/can't run virtual or I'd be using my W7P OEI System Builders Pack and going that route, regardless that MS makes it nearly impossible to download and install W7's SP-1 (which tool me a solid month before WU stopped failing at installing SP-1).

If I can't do it myself, surely repair shops and/or the like might be able to partition and therein load Acer's "eRecovery" software (Acer's drivers) via an Acer recovery disc, then slipstream XPH SP3 w/an appropriate selection of  updates and patches via a slipstream 'CDROM'?

Again if even possible to run XPH when the machine was built to run W7, at the very least I'd sure appreciate finding out how to obtain a slipstream 'CDROM', especially since I know MS dropped support for even W7, that and it's unlikely would a shop do it.

The "AOD250" (aka Acer One D250-1610, Model KAV60 Netbook) has an SNID of 91716770716, PN: LU.S700B.171 and reportedly afforded Premium Performance w/up to Intel Core i7.

Best regards and happ-e-trails to all,

MSHostage

Comment: You're using some pretty weird acronyms that I think even experts in the field wouldn't use.

Comment: There's really no reason Windows XP wouldn't run on such a laptop assuming you have the keys for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are really on the wrong track... In multiple ways.

Win7 is still under full support (and will be for the whole of 2018) . If you have a valid key for it (should be one on that NetBook, possibly hidden beneath the battery) you can request an ISO download from the MS website. As easy as that.
(Please note that due to the current meltdown/spectre panic the MS servers are quite overloaded and slow at the moment.)
Alternatively you can download the ISO downloader tool from www.heidoc.net which gives you an easy interface to download any official MS ISO.

Getting XP on that NetBook can only be done with an USB bootstick. The Acer recovery image isn't helpful as it is not a slipstream install that can be modified to supply a different image. It uses proprietary Acer software. Besides it doesn't provide any XP drivers.

Getting XP to find the internal harddisk, which isn't actually a harddisk but some kind of eMMC storage will require special XP storage drivers integrated into the XP image. (You can't side-load them via F6 and a floppy unless you have a USB floppy drive available. Changes are that this NetBook doesn't even support floppy drives at all.)

Even if you get all that to work you still will have to deal with the fact that all OTHER hardware in that NetBook won't have XP drivers, or only limited functionality in the drivers (like no WPA2 support for the Wifi) that are available.

Even if you can live with that: Your security patches will be years out of date and no modern, secure web-browser will run on the thing. And most modern Wifi networks require WPA2 as a minimum.

Unless you are a masochist looking for punishment: Do yourself a favor and put W7 back on it.

Comment: Since I use my Notebook for internet and e-mail only, once I know those files I wish to retain are clean, I store them on EHD's which I fill up just about annually, and as such (if or when if ever any infections or malware gets past the W7P Notebook's security, likely at most only one EHD might be affected. but for use of my  music, vids and.or .ts files or  and video  them to and a netbook only for running older programs, managing records, music and video,

Comment: “Win7 is still under full support” – it is not. It has Extended Support (ie. security fixes only) until 2020. It is also no longer supported (at all!) on modern CPUs, though that’s irrelevant here.

Comment: @Daniel You are right of course. I had meant to type "under full security patch support", but sometimes I think faster than I can type.